# Multithreading in C - Can a thread functions logic, result in Stopping the main thread execution?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

A beginner here.
I have a requirement to handle the behavior when the server faces a network issue( No network)
Is there any signal handler which could handle that? I am very certain that there is no such thing. However, can it be configured?

If not, I plan to have a ping mechanism between the two servers present on the same system.

Architecture of serverA(central server, has list of all registered servers), For simplicity, using only 1 server extra

```
#----header files
main()
{
 --serverconfig details
 while(1)
 --server_run()
}
```

Similarly Server B, which registers to Server A, has the same architecture.
Now, to counter the network failure scenario, I plan to have a multithreaded central server(A). and insert a ping function inside the while(1) loop of serverB.

I am very confused as to how to end the program if Server A does not receive any ping from the server B.

Server A

```
--headerfiles
main(){
--serverconfig
Thread1withreceivePing()
while(1){
--server_run()
}
}
```

Server B

```
--headerfiles
main(){
--serverconfig

while(1){
Thread1withSendPing()
--server_run()
}
}
```

Can the ServerA program terminate when it does not receive ping for every 2 minutes? Please let me know.

Comment: You don't need threads for that. What's wrong with `if(currentTime - timeWhenPingWasReceived > 120)`?

Comment: This is about sockets, not threads. So maybe tell which socket lib and OS you are using.

Comment: @user253751: if i do not use threads, the server execution will be paused. I want the server to run normally, without waiting for any input initially. I make use of the thread because, I think, otherwise it would keep waiting till the server B pings

Comment: @Lundin I am using Ubuntu 20.04, i make use of these header files #include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

Answer (score 0):

> Can the ServerA program terminate when it does not receive ping for every 2 minutes?

The answer is yes. All threads share the set of global variables (variables with static storage). That means that a thread can change the value of a global variable, and the main thread has just to periodically check it.

Alternatively, a thread can call the exit function. But this looks like an abort procedure, because other threads could be forcibly interrupted in an unsafe situation.

Comment: 'other threads could be forcibly interrupted in an unsafe situation' how, if the process is terminating?